# bootstrap modal click on div appears once

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've used bootstrap modal so that when I click on the div the modal pops up. However, on clicking close, if I click back on the div the modal does not pop up again. Just wondering how I can do this.

The HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" id="userdiv">
    <div class="modal fade " data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                   <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

              </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

The JS:

```
var $modal = $('.modal').modal({
    show: false 
});
$('#userdiv').on('click', function() {
    $modal.modal('show');
});
```

Comment: Looks fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/b501uat6/

Comment: @user1012181 That's because you added a second div with the id="userdiv".

Comment: Is there any restriction on your code? Why not using the data-attributes option? Like: http://www.bootply.com/Dm1LweDUAQ

Comment: I don't want to use the button, just for the user to click on the div area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your `<div class="modal fade>...</div>` outside of your `<div id="userdiv">...</div>`, that way, the `.click()` function will be captured correctly and open the modal:

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" id="userdiv">
  <h4>User Div</h4>
</div>

<div class="modal fade " data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

See this [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zOkOj2x4lj) for an example.

Comment: This version worked for me. Although I'd like to get the version without the JS working as well. Many thanks to all for speedy responses.

Answer (score 1):

This should work without any `JS`

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b501uat6/1/

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3" id="userdiv" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> CLICK EXACTLY ON THE TEXT
    <div class="modal fade " id='myModal' data-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                   <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

              </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll try to get the page working with just HTML. Although with this response it seems this will only work when clicked on CLICK EXACTLY ON THE TEXT. How do I get this to work so clicking anywhere in the div runs the modal?